# Workaround to upload AVIF files

Tags: uploads

Has anyone found a good way to upload AVIF images files through the WordPress media uploader?

I've seen variations of this code posted everywhere:

```
function allowed_mime_types( $mime_types ) {

  //AVIF Images
  $mime_types['avif'] = 'image/avif';

  return $mime_types;
}

add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'allowed_mime_types' );
```

But, when I use that I still get an error:

> Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.

I confirmed that `avif` is added to the list of extensions in the plupload localized script vars, but still no joy. What am I missing?

Comment: Try with adding this plugin for expand security reasons https://wordpress.org/plugins/blob-mimes/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Can you confirm if that plugin allows AVIF uploads? What technique does it use? I took a quick look at the source, but it's a pretty heavy plugin, and I wasn't able to quickly see how it works.

Comment: honestly i've didn't try it, but after looking around, it seems to be the solution.